# Div with fixed with and div with flexible width next to each other

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

In a container which has a 2% padding left and right, I have two div boxes. The left div box has a fixed width of 200px and a fixed margin-right of 60px. I would like the right div to adjust its width the smaller/bigger the browser window gets. How do I achieve that the width of the red box always (independent of the browser width) fills up until the start of the rigth padding of the container, while the blue div keeps its 200px?

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/3vhrst19/3/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="fixed-width"></div>

    <div id="flexible-width"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px;
    background: lightgrey;
}

#fixed-width {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 500px;
    margin-right: 60px;
    background: blue;
}

#flexible-width {
    float: left;
    width: 500px; /* my goal is that the width always fills up independent of browser width */
    height: 500px;
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easially achievable with [`flexbox`](http://learnlayout.com/flexbox.html):

```
#container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px;
  background: lightgrey;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* used so the padding will be inline and not extend the 100% width */
}
```

Where the responsive element fills up the remaining space with a `flex-grow`:

```
#flexible-width {
  flex: 1; /* my goal is that the width always fills up independent of browser width */
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
}
```

*Note that i removed all of your `floats` as it was not necessary in this example.*

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3vhrst19/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `calc` to remove the fixed width and margin width from the 100% width

```css
#container {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px;
  background: lightgrey;
}
#fixed-width {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-right: 60px;
  background: blue;
}
#flexible-width {
  float: left;
  max-width: 500px;
  /* my goal is that the width always fills up independent of browser width */
  width: calc(100% - 260px); /* Use calc to remove the fixed width and margin width from the 100% width */
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="fixed-width"></div>

  <div id="flexible-width"></div>
</div>
```